# Javascript to convert json to html table is not working

Tags: javascript, html

this is my sample js trying to convert some json data to a html table . i copy this html to my desktop and double click it . But there is nothing i could see. there was no error in the inspect element  also.
i could not see any output.

```
<html>
<title>sample</title>
<style>
#mytable,td{
    border:1px solid blue;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" charset="UTF-8">
var obj=[
    {
        id : "001",
        name : "apple",
        category : "fruit",
        color : "red"
    },
    {
        id : "002",
        name : "melon",
        category : "fruit",
        color : "green"
    },
    {
        id : "003",
        name : "banana",
        category : "fruit",
        color : "yellow"
    }
]
var tbl=$("<table/>").attr("id","mytable");
$("#div1").append(tbl);
for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
{
    var tr="<tr>";
    var td1="<td>"+obj[i]["id"]+"</td>";
    var td2="<td>"+obj[i]["name"]+"</td>";
    var td3="<td>"+obj[i]["color"]+"</td></tr>";

   $("#mytable").append(tr+td1+td2+td3); 

}
</script>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="div1"> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$("#div1")` doesn't exist when your script runs. You need to either wrap your script in [`$(document).ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) or move your script to the bottom of the document

Comment: [Capitalize the 1. person sg pronoun](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/172);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have put the js inside the head tag. So when it will be parsed `div id="div1` is not available.
**Solution 1**

```
 Put your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){`
  // your code here
 })
```

**Solution 2**

Put the script tag near closing `body` tag

```
<body>
     // DOM
   <script>
    // your code
   </script>
   </body>
```

[Jsfiddle with $(document).ready(function(){..}](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/quz276L7/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all your code in `$(document).ready` so that they will only be run once the page is loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function()
    var obj=[
        {
            id : "001",
            name : "apple",
            category : "fruit",
            color : "red"
        },
        {
            id : "002",
            name : "melon",
            category : "fruit",
            color : "green"
        },
        {
            id : "003",
            name : "banana",
            category : "fruit",
            color : "yellow"
        }
    ]
    var tbl=$("<table/>").attr("id","mytable");
    $("#div1").append(tbl);
    for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
    {
        var tr="<tr>";
        var td1="<td>"+obj[i]["id"]+"</td>";
        var td2="<td>"+obj[i]["name"]+"</td>";
        var td3="<td>"+obj[i]["color"]+"</td></tr>";

       $("#mytable").append(tr+td1+td2+td3); 

    }
});
```

Other than that, your code should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
<title>sample</title>
<style>
#mytable,td{
    border:1px solid blue;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" charset="UTF-8"></script><!--You forgot to close script link here-->
<script><!--You forgot to open script tag here-->
$(document).ready(function(){
var obj=[
    {
        id : "001",
        name : "apple",
        category : "fruit",
        color : "red"
    },
    {
        id : "002",
        name : "melon",
        category : "fruit",
        color : "green"
    },
    {
        id : "003",
        name : "banana",
        category : "fruit",
        color : "yellow"
    }
]
var tbl = "<table>"
var content="";
for(i=0; i<obj.length;i++){
    content += '<tr><td>' +obj[i]["id"]+ '</td></tr>';
}
content += "</table>"

$('#div1').append(content);

});
/*var tbl=$("<table>").attr("id","mytable");
$("#div1").append(tbl);
for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
{
    var tr="<tr>";
    var td1="<td>"+obj[i]["id"]+"</td>";
    var td2="<td>"+obj[i]["name"]+"</td>";
    var td3="<td>"+obj[i]["color"]+"</td></tr>";
}
 $("#mytable").append(tr+td1+td2+td3); */
</script>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="div1"> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```